# Dumb Edits keep bumping questions

Tags: discussion, editing, bumping, advice

I am wondering if there is a work around to keep my edits from bumping questions. I recently saw a tex error in my answer and fixed it, I don't think that this should bump the question. Also, when I retag things the question automatically gets bumped. I understand the benefit of this, and think it is good policy in general, but in the question I edited I don't think it was necessary.

Basically I am wondering if anybody can recommend some SE-fu that I can practice to keep my dumb edits form bumping the questions to the front page.

PS by dumb edits I mean things that don't pertain to content and are completely superficial.

Comment: I wonder if re-tagging edits count as edits which "don't pertain to content and are completely superficial"...

Comment: SO ... be aware of the bumping.  Do not do minor edits on long-dormant questions.  Limit your self to 1 or 2 per day for important edits on long-dormant questions.  (Of course questions already on the front page do not count against that 1 or 2 limit.)

Comment: @Sean I just found out about this. I do minor changes from time to time (typos in grammar and spelling) just to clean things up. I hadn't realized it bumped up questions. Given the responses already made, it looks like we'll just have to restrain from keeping that kind of editing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sort of thing has come up many times on meta.stackoverflow.com, for example in the question [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers) from October 2009.  The simple answer is "no".

Comment: that is really unfortunate, would it be worth me going over there and voting it up you think? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Sean: I suspect it will make no difference to vote it up, but I can't see how it would hurt.  Searching some combination of the words "edit", "bump", "minor", etc. on meta.SO, will lead you other threads where you can see the reasoning on both sides.

Comment: The reason is to prevent a malicious 2k user from converting a long-dead post to spam.

Answer (score 12):

FYI, edits within 5 minutes of the original post time are treated as "silent" updates and do not bump a post. You could edit a post multiple times in that 5 minute window and no bumping or revisions occur.

So my advice is, try to identify problems in that 5 minute interval, if you can.

Beyond that, editing should push posts up so the community is able to see and vet what is going on.

Answer (score 11):

Dear Sean,

In addition to the fact that there is nothing to be done about this, I don't think you should worry too much about it.  When answers are good, I don't think it hurts if they reappear from time to time on the front page.

Comment: thanks matt. I will take this as a complement. :)